# prettier doesn't format spacing between exported objects

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I use prettier to format my typescript code with the following config. However, prettier doesn't fix spacing/blank line issues as you can see below in the code snippet. There is supposed to be a blank line between `userSignupSchema` and `userLoginSchema` and only one blank line between `userLoginSchema` and `tokenSchema`. I am using VS Code. Any idea how to fix this?

```json
{
    "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier", "plugin:node/recommended"],
    "plugins": ["prettier"],
    "rules": {
      "prettier/prettier": "error",
      "no-unused-vars": "warn",
      "no-console": "off",
      "func-names": "off",
      "no-process-exit": "off",
      "object-shorthand": "off",
      "class-methods-use-this": "off"
    },
    "singleQuote": true
}
```

```js
export const userSignupSchema = z.object({
    name: z.string()
})
export const userLoginSchema = z.object({
    name: z.string()
})


export const tokenSchema = z.object({
    access_token: z.string()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of the ESLint extension: <kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd> to open the panel if it's not open → Output → ESLint. Your ESLint configuration is invalid. You can't have `"singleQuote": true` there. It's Prettier's option, so it should be specified in [Prettier's configuration file](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html).

Comment: The config above is my aslant config. So it's not part of the prettier config.

Comment: Yep, but you use Prettier via the ESLint plugin (eslint-plugin-prettier), so if your ESLint config is broken, you're left without Prettier.